# Adding a README.md file to a c# project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, git, markdown, visual-studio-2015

When adding a README.md file to my c# project in Visual Studio 2015 the file doesn't show in the Solution Explorer. It was also untracked in Team Explorer (using Git), but that's easy to fix.

Does anyone know how to go about adding it to / showing it in Solution Explorer?

Also does anyone know of a VS 2015 add-in to render it nicely in the studio?

Comment: How did you add it to the project?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I did a file/new/file off the menu bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look in the top of the solution explorer for the option add hidden files. It should appear with dotted outline.

If you wish to add it to the project you can right click and press "add to project"

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem in Visual Studio 2022 and found this solution:

In Solution Explorer --> right click on "Solution Items" --> Add --> Existing Item... --> Choose the file README.md